# WWIII novel by fighter plane veteran, set in East Asia (first chapter in Japan)

Tags: identification-request

In 2010 I read a book about WW III and I've been trying to find it again since. It's quite an impossible search since as far as I remember the title is 'war'.

What I remember:

- Written by a fighter plane veteran
- About WW III, mostly happening in eastern Russia, Japan and eastern Asia
- Half the book is written in first person and describes fights on sea, land and in the air. Submarines vs warships, tank battles and fighter plane fights. Lots of tactics. Especially the parts in the air are very elaborate.
- First chapter starts in Japan, just before the war.
- The version I read was a pocket book, I think about 300 pages and it had a blue cover.

I've looked at the wiki page 'WW III speculative fiction' but I don't think it's any of those in the list.

It was epic. Any help on this is much appreciated.

PS. I found the book in a hostel in Australia. Maybe by an Australian author...?

Comment: Welcome to Literature, Roel, and thanks for your question. You've included a lot of information about the book, which is good. If you remember anything else (see [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) for some tips), you can always [edit] your post to include that information. Looking at the list of WW III speculative fiction is a good research step; that's actually what solved our [other WW III speculative fiction question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2768/481). Anyways, welcome to our site, and I hope you find what you're looking for :)

Comment: Have you tried looking through [this list of WW III books](https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/world-war-3), or any other list?

Comment: Could it be [*Ghost Fleet*](https://www.ghostfleetbook.com/the-book/), by Peter Warren Singer and August Cole? I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer because this doesn't match the title being "War" or the author being a fighter plane veteran (both authors are academic experts in political science), but it *is* a WWIII novel mostly taking place in the Pacific, and came up as the 1st and 2nd results when I searched Google for `"world war three" novel australian veteran`. See also [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22749719-ghost-fleet).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, all. I've been through the WW III speculative fiction list and the list of WW III books, but haven't found it yet. Ghost fleet looks like it but is published in 2015 so it can't be that one either.
To be continued..